# What should I do if I haven't received my passport 20 days after my H1B visa interview

Tags: passports

I had my H1-B visa interview about 20 days ago. During the interview I was told that it was approved. Also on the official website it appears as approved. However, I haven't received my passport yet. I called them and they said they can't give me any extra information and they don't reply to my emails. Is there anything I can do. Has anyone else experienced this? How long should I expect for it to take until I will receive my passport? Is there a way to learn more about the status of my application process (I need to know how much to delay my flights and stuff to the US)? Thank you!

Comment: I don't believe you can do anything here. Including any emergency passport return requests. US immigration law is written in a way "we are masters, you are slave". They even could in theory send your case for administrative check (and did not update the status yet).

Comment: But on the official website it says: When administrative processing is required, the consular officer will inform the applicant at the end of the interview. Shouldn't I be told about it? I mean I expected it to appear as "pending" or something not "approved" if that was the case, no?

Comment: As far as I understand administrative check happens if your visa gets refused first (mine got approved and it appears as approved) and they would ask for more documents, which they haven't done yet, after 20 days.

Comment: Yes, administrative processing means that visa has been rejected under the corresponding section. In case if visa approved all they actually have to do is just put a visa sticker into your passport and probably update some databases. The main point is it's just a buracrtic procedure. But administrative processing COULD in theory happen even AFTER visa has been approved at the interview. It is super unlikely, but still possible. Anyway, If ceac still says "approved", the only thing OP can do is to wait. There is no any legal way to make the process faster.